# Как запустить QEMU в Termux?

Tags: linux, qemu, termux

Я пытаюсь запустить виртуальную машину с Debian 11 на QEMU (Termux). Создал qcow2 диск. Пытаюсь `qemu-system-aarch64 -hda system.qcow2 -cdrom debian-11.2.0-netinstall-arm64.iso -boot d -machine none -m 1G -k en-gb`. Выскакивает лишь консоль QEMU. Что делать с этим? Либо, как запустить img-образ для Raspberry на QEMU?

Comment: Пробовал и ```-boot menu=on``` - не помогает

Comment: Может, опцию `-nographic` или `-curses` добавьте?

Comment: ```-curses``` вообще ломает отображение терминала (видимо, оно корректно работает лишь на ПК), а -nographic кидает в QEMU терминал. мб как-то из QEMU Shell запустить debian iso? я не работал до этого с QEMU, кроме 1 раза, когда я успешно ставил Kali (но там запустилось сразу, проблем не было)

Comment: Кстати, а из какого пакета вы установили qemu? Я сейчас глянул в репозиторий termux - их там два

Comment: qemu-system-$(arch), не qemu-system-$(arch)-headless

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте аргумент -vnc :1 и подключитесь VNC Viewer к порту 5901